# Visual Studio keeps resetting window layout to default

Tags: visual-studio, find-all-references

I have VS Community 2017 15.9.3 which I use with Unity.

I have a window layout saved where the results window for 'find all references' is on the right of the screen.

If I apply my window layout (<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + 1</kbd>) and 'find all references' then the window appears on the right.

If I then close the window, and 'find all references' again, the window appears in its default position on the bottom.

So I have to hit <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + 1</kbd> before I 'find all references' *every time*.

This is slowly driving me insane.

Comment: What I do is I dock the Find window in the group with the project tree, because I never use them both at the same time. Once you get used to the new position you won't go back.